# Python zipfile hangs when writing

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to use the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module in Python to create simple zip files:

```
import zipfile

files = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
zip_file_name = 'zipfile_test.zip'

zfh = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w')
for file in files:
  print 'Archiving file %s' % file
  zfh.write(zip_file_name)
zfh.close()
```

The files a-h are in my working directory and are empty, use `touch a b c d e f g h` to test.

After adding the first 7 items to the zip file, it hangs on the last one but keeps writing to the zip file until space is exhausted.  This happens on the two systems I have tested it on, one with Python 2.4.3, the other with Python 2.6.2.  If the number of files is less than 6 or 7, the zip file is created without any problems.  Otherwise it fails after between 7-15 files and start writing junk to the end of the file.  I have tried changing:

```
  zfh.write(zip_file_name)
```

to:

```
  zfh.write(zip_file_name, zip_file_name, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

which sometimes allows me to write a couple more files but inevitably fails as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're putting *the zip file* into the zip file:

```
zfh.write(zip_file_name)
```

Should be:

```
zfh.write(file)
```

Comment: Thats the kind of mistake thats difficult to spot without a fresh pair of eyes.